# Compiling an OCaml Book example on Hashtbl

Tags: ocaml

I've tried to compile the following example

```
open Core.Std
module Foo_and_bar : sig
    type t = S of string | I of int
    include Hashable.S with type t := t
  end = struct
    module T = struct
      type t = S of string | I of int with sexp, compare
      let hash t1 t2 = (hashData t1)
    end
    include T
    include Comparable.Make(T)
  end;;
```

with `camlopt -o exec core.cmxa algebra.ml` that could be found on this [book](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/maps-and-hash-tables.html) but as a result, I obtain an error with **sexp** declaration. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Core library comes with a tool that simplifies your life. It is named `corebuild`. With it you can compile just with:

```
corebuild algebra.native
```

And it will produce executable named `algrebra.native`

What concerning your try, then you are referring to `core.cmxa` and `ocamlopt` doesn't know where to find it. Moreover, you need to use `camlp4` preprocessor, to enable syntax extensions. With `ocamlfind` wrapper around `ocamlopt` this can be achieved quite easily:

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -thread -syntax camlp4o -package core.syntax algebra.ml -o exec
```

Here, `-syntax camlp4o` enables syntax extensions, `-package core.syntax` enables core and, also enables Core's syntax extensions.

But I still suggest to use `corebuild`, at least for the start.

Comment: So this library completely substitutes the standard OCaml one? In the same source, I have a declaration module `IntSet = Set.Make( 
  struct
    let compare =Pervasives.compare
    type t = int
  end)`. So I have to replace it with the sets from this other base library?

Comment: yes it is. And you must be careful not to accidentally hit the stock library. Good news, is that they already have instantiated maps, sets, hashtables, etc for all types. For example, `IntSet` is available under `Int.Set`. There're also `Int.Map`, `Int.Table`, `Int.Hash_set`, etc